# Registering an accelerometer listener with a custom rate

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, frequency, rate

```
private static int SENSOR_DELAY_SLOW = 5000000;

sensMngr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

sensMngr.registerListener(this, sensMngr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SENSOR_DELAY_SLOW);
```

I want to capture the sensor's data every 5 seconds but it ignores my desired rate. The listener captures values even over 400 times per second.

Of course I can filter incoming data manually in the *onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)* method, but my primary aim is to reduce the battery drain.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int%29)

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I have noticed this too (with Samsung Galaxy Tab 2). I seemed to get the slowest update rate using SENSOR_DELAY_UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI and you're going to have to filter down from there. There are only 4 selectable speeds and you can't define your own. SENSOR_DELAY_UI tends to go a max of around 3 samples per second and since you are getting results when the sensor values change it can be a few seconds between samples. This will all vary from device to device.

There is no way to define a fixed rate for sensor value delivery in Android.